# Javascript undefined error even if checked before

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
if (target && thisLastCell) {
   if (target.html() && thisLastCell.html()) {
      while(
         (target.html().length > 0 
          || target.hasClass('notop') 
          || target.hasClass('event-cell')
         ) 
         || 
         (thisLastCell.html().length > 0 
          || thisLastCell.hasClass('notop') 
          || thisLastCell.hasClass('event-cell')
         )
      ) {
         // some more code
      }
   }
}
```

I get 'undefined' error even though I checked before with `if (target && thisLastCell) {` and with `if (target.html() && thisLastCell.html()) {`

Edit from comments: target is defined as:

```
var target = $('#calendar-full tr#hour_'+sHour+'_'+tr+' td:nth-child('+colNum+')');
```

The error in javascript console is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

How is this possible?

Comment: provide a jsFiddle link ?

Comment: What is `undefined`? Is it the variables? I think you may get an undefined function error. Please provide more code and/or the full error.

Comment: I can't repeat it in jsFiddle because the code is quite complicated. The target id jQuery select:
`var target = $('#calendar-full tr#hour_'+sHour+'_'+tr+' td:nth-child('+colNum+')');`

Comment: Please read this: [mcve]  if you can't reproduce it yourself in a minimal fiddle, then how are we to reproduce it?

Comment: Try check with `if( target.length && thisLastCell.length )`, because your check could be `true`, even if jQuery doesn't find any elements.

Comment: Can you split the two tests?  To determine if it's `target` or `thisLastCell`.  Your comments show that `target` is defined from `$(...)` but no details on `thisLastCell`

Comment: `$("xxx").html().length` will give 'Cannot read propety of null' (not of undefined) - so I suspect it's thisLastCell that's the issue.

Comment: `var thisLastCell = $('#calendar-full tr#hour_'+eHour+'_'+tr2).prev('tr').find('td:nth-child('+colNum+')');`
This is thisLastCell declaration. I guess it cant find the exact element. But How to check that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The error I got because I changed the `target` code and `thisLastCell` code inside the `while` brackets and thats why the above checks did not checked anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If `target` is undefined then it will still throw an error (I think because of stricter checking, though don't quote me on that). 
If you wrap it in a `typeof` declaration first then it works fine, e.g.

```
if (typeof(target) !== 'undefined' && thisLastCell) {
  // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. `Boolean(undefined)` is false so the example code will *not* throw an error if `target` is "undefined".

Comment: `var a = undefined; if (a) {}` does not throw an error.

Comment: True, but `if (target && thisLastCell) {}` does throw an error

Comment: Possibly because in your example `a` is still declared, even though initialised to undefined? Whereas there's no history of `target` at all?

Comment: Sure, but I strongly assume `target` *has* been declared.

Comment: `var target = $('#calendar-full tr#hour_'+sHour+'_'+tr+' td:nth-child('+colNum+')');`
This is the target declaration

Comment: And none of the above helped me. Still throws error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: You never told us about `length`. I asked for the complete error before. Edit your question @MārcisP!